# Catch infinite while loop in chrome/safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, while-loop

I've written a function to catch a loop after it has run over a specified time.

```
var t1 = new Date().getTime();
while(true){
    //general code in here...

    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')); //This causes the problem

    if(isInfinite(t1,3000)){
        alert('Loop stopped after 3 seconds')
        break;
    }       
}


function isInfinite(t1,timeLimit){
    var t2 = new Date().getTime();
    if(t2-t1> timeLimit){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

It works as expected, but when I try to append nodes to the document it fails to catch in chrome & safari.
What's weird is it works when I have the debugger running, and it works in FF. What is causing this?

Comment: You need to give the processor a breather. Use setTimeout instead of creating elements and Dom manipulation in a tight loop

Comment: Yes I wouldn't normally do this, this section will be part of a tool that I am creating for beginners, and they might do this. So I still need it to catch.

Comment: @mplungjan any infinite while loop will kill the processor, which is what I am trying to address, so your advice is misplaced.

Comment: How can it be misplaced when the end result is:don't do that. You can crash the browser in several ways, so learning not to is perhaps the lesson needed?

Comment: Go here http://jsbin.com/ and copy in <script>while(true){}</script> and you will understand what I am talking about. Sure the user shouldn't do it, but occasionally it will happen by mistake. Why not give them a helpful alert instead of crashing the whole browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are firing this JS code before DOM is ready. Here is my implementation.

```
<!--Basically I am firing this script with onload event function.-->
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <script>
            function init() {
                alert("asg");
                var t1 = new Date().getTime();
                while(true) {
                    //general code in here...
                    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')); //This causes the problem
                    if(isInfinite(t1, 3000)) {
                        alert('Loop stopped after 3 seconds')
                        break;
                    }
                }

                function isInfinite(t1, timeLimit) {
                    var t2 = new Date().getTime();
                    if(t2 - t1 > timeLimit) {
                        return truite;
                    } else return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, this script is most likely going to crash depending on how browser manufacturers have set their restriction on looping (This usually occurs when main thread is blocked). So I think it is much better idea to use setTimeout function for this example.

---

#### Just for your interest

Javascript is event based and it has only 1 thread. You have mentioned that you are going to show it to beginners. Why not explain them event based nature of JS instead of doing it this way?

Comment: This still doesn't catch it. I am mostly curious as to why it catches when debugging but not when it is running. And I just want it to catch no matter what is put in the loop.